# C++: cannot convert A::lambda() to B::*function pointer in assignment

Tags: c++, oop, lambda, function-pointers

I have a OneWireDriver class:

```
class OneWireDriver;
typedef void (OneWireDriver::*StateHandler)(void);

class OneWireDriver{
    Timer *timer; //a pointer to a Timer object working for this OneWireDriver object
    void registerTimerCallback(void); //a method to set this timer's callback function
    StateHandler stateHandler; //a handler pointing to a function OneWireDriver will execute from the current state
    void executeState(void){ //a method to execute the function saved in stateHandler from another class
        (this->*stateHandler)();
    } 
    //...
};
```

Class Timer has:

```
class Timer;
typedef void (Timer::*TimerCallback)(void);

class Timer{
    TimerCallback callback; //a pointer to a callback function which is executed when its period elapses
    void executeCallback(void){ //a method to execute the function saved in callback from another class
        (this->*callback)();
    } 
    //...
};
```

The challenge now is to make Timer's object able to run executeState() on the OneWireDriver object which the Timer belongs to **without the timer explicitly knowing the OneWireDriver object to which it belongs.**

My teacher advised me to try to use **lambdas** for that, so I tried:

```
void OneWireDriver::registerTimerCallback(void){
    this->timer->callback = [&]{ this->executeState(); };
};
```

Which fails to compile with:

```
cannot convert 'OneWireDriver::registerTimerCallback()::<lambda()>' to 'TimerCallback {aka void (Timer::*)()}' in assignment
```

At this point, I doubt if it is even possible to use lambdas for assigning a method from one class to be executed from another class unless the other class knows the first one's identity (because it must not know).

1) Can lambda expressions help me solve the challenge?

2) If not, is there any way to solve the problem of Timer object calling a method of OneWireDriver object it belongs to, without knowing the OneWireDriverObject? Or a potential workaround that the Timer does not have to know its OneWireDriver object?

Comment: `callback` is a member function and needs an object to be called on (`(object.*callback)()`). The lambda is a free function, not a member function and can be called directly (`lambda()`) without any object. They cannot be compatible. So the answer to your first question is "no".

Comment: But I suppose we need a `this->executeState()` in the lambda's body to assign a function called on a proper object

Comment: `typedef void (Timer::*TimerCallback)(void);` This expects a pointer to a *member* function, which is not compatible to either regular functions or lambdas. This is a rather, shall we say, suboptimal choice. A good callback type is `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: That `this` pointer was captured when defining the lambda and is stored in the lambda closure object. It is not passed to the lambda when you call the lambda, but when you created it.

Comment: Also, *capturing* lambdas can't be converted to function pointers. `std::function` is definitely your friend in this situation.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I am having quite a hard time #including <functional> in my project because of numerous 'template with C linkage' errors in my project. Could you propose ny other solution not using std::function?

Comment: I have no idea how it is possible to get this error, unless you are including `functional` inside of `extern "C"` block. Don't do that.